# Get value out of string with a regular expression

Tags: regex

Regular expressions are driving me nuts. Let's say I have this string:

```
rid=1234567"
```

How do I get the value `1234567` out of this string? And that number can be anything, with any length, but also characters and numbers.

Comment: Seems odd to see such a question from a user with 1K+ rep.

Comment: Ha! I know, but I never used regular expresions very much before

Comment: Did you even make a _feeble attempt_ to search?

Comment: I think devnull means about the low quality of the question: you don't even show what you've tried so far, which regex engine you're referring to...

Comment: Why Regex you could just split the string?

Comment: [0-9]+: will look for at least one number, specify a Programming language, else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a capture group

```
=([1-9a-zA-Z]*)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Wo2mmx4lsGNt4HwQ)